# How to make Modal View transparent?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can not make transparent modal View. All previous Views can. But when switch to modal: it animates and makes background black.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to present a semi-transparent overlay over the Use the `modalPresentationStyle` property.

In iOS 8, there is the [`UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext) that will take care of this automatically. To support previous versions, you have to do this manually, for example using the `UIModalPresentationCustom` presentation style, that gives you full control over the effect.

Comment: I just trying to make one background in app. I use tabbarcontroller as main controller. One tab is TableView with details. When i trying open details - blank screen. I don't know how to choose Custom presentation in this case